# Again Integrate with singularities

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Integrate[1/(a x + Sqrt[b x^2 - c]), {x, 1, d}]
```

where `a,b,c` are positive values. Mathematica runs this forever.

Comment: In general, fixing assumptions makes timing considerably shorter.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulubitch: Only assumptions do not help here.

Comment: Assumptions that force the denominator to be nonzero and force the radicand to be nonnegative can help. I used for example `Assumptions -> {a > 0, d > 1, b > 1, 0 < c < 1}`; that takes a minute or three to run to completion.

Comment: @DanielLichblau: `Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c}, 
  Implies[a > 0 && b > 1 && 0 < c < 1, 
   a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && Sqrt[c/b] < 1]], Reals]` produces `True`. You consider a partial case of the conditions from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Making assumptions and no conditions

```
Integrate[1/(a x + Sqrt[b x^2 - c]),{x, 1, d},Assumptions->d>= 1&&a>0&& b > 0 && c > 0, 
GenerateConditions -> False]
```

, we have

```
  (* (1/(2 (a^2 - b)))(a Log[1 - a/Sqrt[b - c]] - 
  a Log[1 + a/Sqrt[b - c]] + 2 Sqrt[b] Log[b + Sqrt[b] Sqrt[b - c]] - 
  a Log[a^2 - b + c] + a Log[c + (a^2 - b) d^2] - 
  a Log[1 - (a d)/Sqrt[-c + b d^2]] + 
  a Log[1 + (a d)/Sqrt[-c + b d^2]] - 
  2 Sqrt[b] Log[b d + Sqrt[b] Sqrt[-c + b d^2]]) *)
```

PS. In order to obtain a nonformal result (in version 12.2), one should make an additional assumption which guarantees positivity of `b*x^2-c`:

```
Integrate[1/(a x + Sqrt[b x^2 - c]), {x, 1, d}, 
Assumptions -> d >= 1 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && Sqrt[c/b] < 1]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(a*Log[-a + Sqrt[b - c]] -  a*Log[a + Sqrt[b - c]] + 2*Sqrt[b]*Log[b + Sqrt[b*(b - c)]] -  a*Log[a^2 - b + c] + a*Log[c + (a^2 - b)*d^2] -  a*Log[-(a*d) + Sqrt[-c + b*d^2]] +  a*Log[a*d + Sqrt[-c + b*d^2]] -  2*Sqrt[b]*Log[b*d + Sqrt[b*(-c + b*d^2)]])/(2*(a^2 - b)),  a^2 != b && Sqrt[b - c] <= a && d > 1 &&  (Sqrt[c]*Re[1/Sqrt[-a^2 + b]] < 1 ||  d < Sqrt[c]*Re[1/Sqrt[-a^2 + b]] || NotElement[Sqrt[-a^2 + b],  Reals]) && ((a^2 + c >= b &&  ((a^2 < b && Re[(1 + Sqrt[c]/Sqrt[-a^2 + b])/(1 - d)] <= 0) ||  NotElement[(1 + Sqrt[c]/Sqrt[-a^2 + b])/(1 - d), Reals])) ||  (a^2 > b && NotElement[(1 + Sqrt[c]/Sqrt[-a^2 + b])/(1 - d),  Reals]))]`

Comment: @AntoinAntonov: I didn't edit your posts. Do you understand me?

Comment: Missed a spot, btw.  There's a "rollback" button in the edit history that's probably more appropriate.  (I prefer Anton's edit though.)

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematica* can quickly find the antiderivative, so another approach is to evaluate the antiderivative, call it $\psi$, between the limits, as

```
ψ = Integrate[1/(a x + Sqrt[b x^2 - c]), x]

(ψ /. x -> d) - (ψ /. x -> 1) // Simplify
```

This gives
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try `Rubi`

```
<< Rubi`
Int[1/(a x + Sqrt[b x^2 - c]), {x, 1, d}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nasser (@does not work)`Rubi` produces a formal answer. Am I not right?

Comment: That's not a definite integral. It's an indefinite integral in a pretty dress.